# Installing Python packages on windows 7

Tags: python, path, installation, pip, package

I am trying to install python packages in windows 7 and I am getting this error. "    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\pysqlite"

```
Here is the full "log" 

    Collecting tweeply
  Using cached tweeply-0.6.tar.gz
Collecting Flask==0.10.1 (from tweeply)
  Using cached Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz
Collecting Flask-OAuth==0.12 (from tweeply)
  Using cached Flask-OAuth-0.12.tar.gz
Collecting click==3.3 (from tweeply)
  Using cached click-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyzmq==14.3.0 (from tweeply)
  Using cached pyzmq-14.3.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting twitter==1.14.3 (from tweeply)
  Using cached twitter-1.14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting SQLAlchemy==0.9.9 (from tweeply)
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-0.9.9.tar.gz
Collecting psycopg2==2.6 (from tweeply)
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz
Collecting pysqlite==2.6.3 (from tweeply)
  Downloading pysqlite-2.6.3.tar.gz (76kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module

    ----------------------------------------

    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\pysqlite
```

I am using python 3.4.3 on windows 7 (64 bit) using Pycharm 4.0.6 (the command line didn't work either). I tried using the command `py -m pip install tweeply` (I also tried other packages)

I successfully installed this package with the same pycharm software and version of python yesterday on my laptop but I am unable to install it with my desktop.

I set the path variable, have the latest version of pip and esay_install, have PostgreSQL 9.4 (to deal with an other error I had) and can't find out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you using the 32 or 64 bit version of Python 3.4.3? Many third-party extension don't work with the 64-bit version.

Comment: I am using the 64 bit. I thought I tried the 32 but I will try again and comment if that worked